# EventListener never get's hit

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I'm ripping my hair off at the moment! Now hoping that one of you guys can help me solving my (now two) problem(s).

First one.

I've got the following code:

```
private var tmpLoader:Loader = new Loader();

private function myFunction():void {
tmpLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
tmpLoader.load(new URLRequest(front.url)); 
}

        private function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void 
        {
            var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = e.target as LoaderInfo;
            var loadedBitmap:Bitmap = loaderInfo.content as Bitmap;

            var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            sprite.addChild(loadedBitmap);

            addChild(sprite);

            sprite.x = 100;
            sprite.y = 200;         
        }
```

I should also mention that the front.url is equal to a local file path to an image on my computer. Like: "file:///Users/bob/Desktop/potrait.jpg"

My first problem is; why doesn't my onLoadComplete get's hit? Could it have something to do with the url/file path is passed as an argument to URLRequest? Or what could it be?

My second problem revolves hair loss and will also be solved if my first problem gets solved ;-)

Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first load your content than go for eventListener
just like this:

```
tmpLoader.load(new URLRequest(front.url));
tmpLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
```

and make sure that there is no problem with your URL address

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Event.COMPLETE for tmpLoader instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, that does not make any difference. Thanx anyway.